# Can purchased apps from Android be downloaded on Windows phone?

Tags: apps

I'm looking at switching from an Android phone over to a Windows phone, specifically the Nokia Lumia 925. Now I have my Google account linked to my Android where it stores all my purchase history, can I link that Google account to my Windows phone to be able to download apps I've already purchased? Taking into consideration that the same app may be available in the Windows Marketplace, I know for a fact that Asphalt 7 is in each store which is one that I have purchased.

I did see [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/syncing-windows-phone-with-google-apps-free-edition), which is kind of similar, but still haven't been able to find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application licences are not shared between ecosystems, so if you bought one on Android you will have to buy it again on Windows Phone (if available).

However, it is possible that some in-app purchases may be shared between ecosystem e.g. I bought some comics from Comixology on Android and was able to download them again on my iPad for free. This is heavily dependent on the developers implementation and is probably the exception and not the norm.

Answer (score 1):

No, only apps downloaded from the [Windows Phone App Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store) can be installed on a common device. On a dev unlocked device, apps can be side-loaded, but only ones that were made for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

That would be amazing, wouldn't it? It would also nullify the biggest **percieved** weakness for the Windows Phone platform i.e. fewer apps than those available on either the Android or iOS platforms.

I think your question is one worth asking though. The reason I say this is because certain Android apps do work on BlackBerry's BB10 platform. However, to be able to achieve this compatibility, BlackBerry had to include extra components in their platform.

From a strategic point of view, it probably made sense for BlackBerry to include support for Android apps- the company is in a lot of trouble and they needed to do take some steps to rectify the situation.

In the case of Windows Phone, however, things are different. A year ago, Windows Phone wasn't as well known as it is today. If Microsoft was to decide that it will make Windows Phone support Android apps, that might me Microsoft implying that they don't have any hope that developers will make native apps for Windows Phone.

The difference between Microsoft and BlackBerry is that Microsoft doesn't need to take such extreme measures. They have built a great OS and now the app developers are coming on board too.

Sorry to go off on a tangent but rather than just saying that it is not possible, I figure it might be better to shed some more light on the broader picture.

Comment: Let it be known too that when BlackBerry opened up recently to all android apps, they let themselves vulnerable to malicious apps. They are now open to and victim of large security holes.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in my opinion, as you are addressing the issue of running Android binaries on WP. The question however was targeted towards multi-platform licensing, i.e. using paid apps available for both platforms while only paying once.

Comment: Fair enough. I misread the question.